# ATH price and date in label

Tags: pine-script

how can I display a label that will contain the price of ATH and the date of this ATH
with this code i was able to find ATH

```
ATH_month = highest(high, 800)
```

I know ATH was in April

I was trying to create a label with the price and date of this ATH

```
if ATH_month == month==4
var x1 = label.new(time + 60*(time - time[1]), close, xloc=xloc.bar_time, text = tostring(ATH_month) + " | " + tostring(month), color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_left)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect and remember the last time a higher price was detected as your script is executing on the dataset:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
i_src = input(high)
var float hi = i_src
var float hiTime = na
if i_src > hi
    hi := i_src
    hiTime := time

f_print(_text) => var _label = label.new(bar_index, na, _text, xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, color(na), label.style_none, color.gray, size.large, text.align_left), label.set_xy(_label, bar_index, highest(10)[1]), label.set_text(_label, _text)
f_tickFormat() =>
    _s = tostring(syminfo.mintick)
    _s := str.replace_all(_s, "25", "00")
    _s := str.replace_all(_s, "5",  "0")
    _s := str.replace_all(_s, "1",  "0")

f_print("ATH: " + tostring(hi, f_tickFormat()) + str.format(" on {0,date,full}", hiTime))

// For debugging
plotchar(change(hi), "ATH", "•", location.top, size = size.tiny)
plot(hi)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. You helped me a lot. now i'm trying to parse the logic of the above script) you know pine script very well

Comment: Feel free to ask if you don't understand something in the code.

Comment: do you have a telegram so I can write to you directly? I'm willing to pay you for your help. here is my telegram @ efefefef22

Comment: I don't do paid work but PineCoders maintain a list of Trusted Pine Programmers for Hire:
https://www.tradingview.com/?solution=43000601677

Comment: I just wanted to pay you for help as a token of gratitude. You know the pine script very well and I just as well want to learn it)

Comment: can you help me. I tried to determine the lowest price. on the BTC / USDT chart
minimum price 2817
your code shows me 3364.5
I tried this with your code, which changed a bit. could you tell me what is my mistake?

`var float high_bar = low
var float price_time = na

if low < high_bar
    high_bar := low
    price_time := time
    
f_print(text) => var x = label.new(bar_index, open),
     label.set_xy(x, bar_index, highest(10)[1]),
     label.set_text(x, text)
f_print(tostring(high_bar) + " - " + str.format(" on {0,date,full}", price_time))`

Comment: Can't read code from comment. Add to the end of your OP by editing it.

Comment: How do I use your code to determine the smallest price, then print it to the label and specify the date of that price?

Comment: Show us your attempt to adapt our code for the ATL by adding under your original answer.

Comment: i just mean high replaced to low

Comment: I tried to do all this with the code that you wrote to me above